# Cannot call struct properties from HAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the following code in my controller:

```
@nav_items = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.new
@nav_items[:home]       =   Struct::NavItem.new("Home", nil, "/", "icon-home")
@nav_items[:about]      =   Struct::NavItem.new("About", nil, "/about", "icon-heart")
@nav_items[:contact]    = Struct::NavItem.new("Contact", nil, "/contact", "icon-envelope")
if (current_user != nil && current_user.admin?)
  @nav_items[:admin_divider] = Struct::NavItem.new(nil, "divider-vertical", nil, nil)
  @nav_items[:admin]    = Struct::NavItem.new("Admin", nil, "/admin", "")
end
```

And the following in my view:

```
- @nav_items.each do |nav_item|
  %li{ :class => nav_item[:class] }
  %a{ :href => nav_item[:link] }= nav_item[:text]
```

And my struct definition: `Struct.new("NavItem", :text, :class, :link, :icon_class)`

I'm relatively new to Ruby, Rails, and HAML, but in another project using ERB rendering, code like that worked fine. I've tried referencing properties by doing something like `nav_item.link` as well, but that still does not work.

The error I get with my current code is:

> Symbol as array index

By using code like `nav_item.link`:

> undefined method `link' for #< Array:0x126970ff0 >

As this is my first time using HAML, I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a `@nav_items` hash iterated with a single variable `|nav_item|`, which will yield the key-value pair as an array. Try `-@nav_items.each do |_,nav_item|` or `-@nav_items.values.each do |nav_item|`.

Comment: Hey hey! Just like that, magic. I'm still sort of scratching my head as to why it would be fine using ERB rendering (`<% @x.each do |y| %>`), but this makes a lot more sense now. Thank you very much!